# How to expand $x^{1/3}-c^{1/3}$ into $(x-c)y$ for some $y$

Tags: factoring, binomial-theorem

> How to expand $x^{1/3}-c^{1/3}$ into $(x-c)y$ for some $y$

I know $x^3-c^3=(x-c)(x^2+xc+c^2)$ but I can't figure out how to pull this off with $1/3$ instead of $3$

Comment: I don't think any similar rule applies for non-integers powers in terms of factorising polynomials

Comment: Technically speaking that isn't "expanding" so much as factoring.

Comment: "I don't think any similar rule applies for non-integers powers in terms of factorising polynomials"  Sure there are.  Just take $\sqrt[k] x = M$ and $x = M^k$ anc $\sqrt[k]c = N$.  Then $x -c = (M^k - N^k)(M^{k-1}+ ... N^{k-1})= (\sqrt[k] x - \sqrt[k] c)(\sqrt[k] x^{k-1} +.... + \sqrt[k]c^{k-1})$

Answer (score 1):

Replace $x$ with $(x^{\frac 13})^3$ and $c = (c^{\frac 13})^3$ and so

$x - c = (x^{\frac 13})^3 - (c^{\frac 13})^3 = (x^{\frac 13} - c^{\frac 13})((x^{\frac 13})^2 + x^{\frac 13}y^{\frac 13} + (c^{\frac 13})^2)$

So

$(x -c) \frac 1{x^{\frac 23} + x^{\frac 13}y^{\frac 13} + c^{\frac 23}}= x^{\frac 13}- c^{\frac 13}$

So $y = \frac 1{x^{\frac 23} + x^{\frac 13}y^{\frac 13} + c^{\frac 23}}$

There *IS* the assumption that $x^{\frac 23} + x^{\frac 13}y^{\frac 13} + c^{\frac 23} \ne 0$.  But if $x^{\frac 23} + x^{\frac 13}y^{\frac 13} + c^{\frac 23} = 0$ then $x - c = (x^{\frac 13})^3 - (c^{\frac 13})^3 = (x^{\frac 13} - c^{\frac 13})((x^{\frac 13})^2 + x^{\frac 13}y^{\frac 13} + (c^{\frac 13})^2) = 0$ and $x = c$ and $x^{\frac 13} = c^{\frac 13}$ and $y$ could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your way is right, let use that

$$A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$$

with $A^3=x$ and $B^3=c$.

Then

$$x^{1/3}-c^{1/3}=(x-c)\cdot \frac1{x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}c^{1/3}+c^{2/3}}$$

Answer (score -1):

Write $w=x-c$.  You want to expand in powers of $w$.  So, as $w \to 0$ we have
\begin{align}
x^{1/3} &= (c+w)^{1/3} = c^{1/3}\left(1+\frac{w}{c}\right)^{1/3}
\\
&= c^{1/3}\left(1+\frac{w}{3c}-\frac{w^2}{9c^2}+\frac{5w^3}{81c^3}+\dots\right)
\\
&= c^{1/3}+\frac{w}{3c^{2/3}}-\frac{w^2}{9c^{5/3}}+\frac{5w^3}{81c^{8/3}}+\dots
\\
x^{1/3} - c^{1/3} &= \frac{w}{3c^{2/3}}-\frac{w^2}{9c^{5/3}}+\frac{5w^3}{81c^{8/3}}+\dots
\\
&= w\left(\frac{1}{3c^{2/3}}-\frac{w}{9c^{5/3}}+\frac{5w^2}{81c^{8/3}}+\dots\right)
\\
&= (x-c)\left(\frac{1}{3c^{2/3}}-\frac{x-c}{9c^{5/3}}+\frac{5(x-c)^2}{81c^{8/3}}+\dots\right)
\end{align}

Of course the last factor is exactly
$$
\frac{x^{1/3}-c^{1/3}}{x-c} ,
$$
which is an analytic function (removable singularity) near $x=c$.

Comment: Good God! Really?